# can't create any table SQLite / Android

Tags: android, sqlite

As the topic imply i've a few problems creating a new table in sqlite. what ever i do with my code i can't create new table in the db. if i look at the db there's just the android_metadata tb and nothing else. the code to create a new one is:

```
...
this.createTable(R.string.nametable, "_id INT PRIMARY KEY, " + "parentID INT, " + "name TEXT");
...

public void createTable(int id, String sql) {
        String table = this.getStringById(id);
        String _sql = "CREATE TABLE " + table + "(" + sql + ")";
        Log.d("Controller.createTable", _sql);
        this.mCurrentConnection.rawQuery(_sql, null);
        try {
            Cursor c = this.Select(id, "*", null);
            c.close(); 
            Log.d("Controller.createTable", "create finished");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Controller.createTable", "can't create table: " + table);
        }
    }
```

i open or create the db in the contructor of my app

```
if(this.mCurrentConnection == null || !this.mCurrentConnection.isOpen()) {
            this.mCurrentConnection = this.mContext.openOrCreateDatabase(this.mDB, Context.MODE_PRIVATE , null);
        }
```

I've tried everything: changing names of db / tb, reinstall app, placing ";" or not at the end of the command, tried it with a new clean vm.
i did not found any helpful existing post/answer that fix my prob.
if i execute the _sql statement

```
CREATE TABLE name_table(_id INT PRIMARY KEY, parentID INT, name TEXT)
```

in phpmyadmin (MySQL) everything works fine.

I'de be happy if you could help me.

regards Alex

EDIT: (answer for a comment below)

@VikramBodicherla: that's the prob. the create statement itself did not cause any exeption. the select (check) statement does throw an

> 04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305): Error inserting parentid=-1
>   name=blabla 
>   04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
>
> no such table: name_table: , while compiling: INSERT INTO
>   name_table(parentid, name) VALUES(?, ?); 04-30 07:34:14.834:
>   E/Database(305):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_compile(Native Method)
>   04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compile(SQLiteProgram.java:110)
>   04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
>   04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
>   04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1027)
>   04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1413)
>   04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1286)
>   04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):  at
>   unicorn.Heurazio.Controller.addName(Controller.java:156) 04-30
>   07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):    at
>   unicorn.Heurazio.Controller.install(Controller.java:135) 04-30
>   07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):    at
>   unicorn.Heurazio.StartUpActivity.onCreate(StartUpActivity.java:22)
>   04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
>   04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
>   04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119) 04-30
>   07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
>   04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-30
>   07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 04-30 07:34:14.834:
>   E/Database(305):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363) 04-30
>   07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-30
>   07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 04-30 07:34:14.834:
>   E/Database(305):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.runZygoteInit.java:860)
>   04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 04-30
>   07:34:14.834: E/Database(305):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Have you tried using this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Comment: Can you also post the logcat stacktrace please? I assume you are running into an exception.

Comment: yes tried it too. but i think i did not need one so i skiped this approach. correct me if i'm wrong afaik SQLiteOpenHelper is for Upgrades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really really really want to use the [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) class and its associated [pattern](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db): it is not just for upgrades, it handles cleanly creating the table(s) as well.

Also, your create statement should probably look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE name_table (_id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, parentID INTEGER, name TEXT)
```

EDIT: from your trace, your CREATE TABLE is never run (hence the table doesn't exist). use the SQLiteOpenHelper and the [`execSQL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) function to create the table and you should be all set.

Comment: every primkey is autoincrement in sqlite [link](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1). hmmmm kay i try it (again)

Comment: okay, now i know why it did not worked.

i've tried two approaches

1: implemented the SQLiteOpenHelper (exactly like example) -> worked

2: tried it again without SQLiteOpenHelper but with execSQL (not rawQuery) -> also worked

the mistake was using "rawQuery" instead of "execSQL". i thought "CREATE TABLE ..." does return somthing like true on success. but apparently it dosen't.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305): Error inserting parentid=-1 name=blabla 04-30 07:34:14.834: E/Database(305): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:

According to your error stack are you trying to insert -1 as the parentid?? parentid is Primary key and does not accept negative value

Comment: CREATE TABLE name_table(_id INT PRIMARY KEY, parentID INT, name TEXT) | it's not primkey ;) _id is ... ;)